# How to Filter Data using three different object

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to make these three objects show in an HTML page. How would i go about achieving this.

Im trying to make a products page where it shows all three products on the page.

I have parsed the data, but not sure if thats the most sufficient way of showing the products on a html page. Is parsing the data the only way to show these products?

My script.js

```
var white = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816001.html",
    "title": "White T Shirt",
    "Description": "A white t-shirt"
}

var black = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816002.html",
    "title": "Black T Shirt",
    "Description": "A black t-shirt"
}

var blue = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816078.html",
    "title": "Blue T Shirt",
    "Description": "A blue t-shirt"
}


var whitet = document.getElementById('whitet');
whitet.innerHTML = white.title;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Products</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="whitet">Nothing</div>
    </div>
    <script src="assests/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried to do this? Also, you are asking multiple questions which appears you are asking for people to write code for you. That is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In which format are you willing to show the value from the object ? any custom card ??

Comment: @JagadishLenka yes a custom card.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your products into an array. Then, using `array#map` generate your HTML format and show it by adding it to your HTML.

```js
const white = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816001.html",
    "title": "White T Shirt",
    "Description": "A white t-shirt"
  },
  black = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816002.html",
    "title": "Black T Shirt",
    "Description": "A black t-shirt"
  },
  blue = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816078.html",
    "title": "Blue T Shirt",
    "Description": "A blue t-shirt"
  },
  content = [white, black, blue].map(o => {
    return `<a href=${o.title}>${o.title}</a><div>${o.Description}</div>`
  }).join('<br>');
document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Products</p>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="products">Nothing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a search box for the product list here is one example.

```js
var collection=[];
var white = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816001.html",
    "title": "White T Shirt",
    "Description": "A white t-shirt"
}

var black = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816002.html",
    "title": "Black T Shirt",
    "Description": "A black t-shirt"
}

var blue = {
    "url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0685816078.html",
    "title": "Blue T Shirt",
    "Description": "A blue t-shirt"
}
collection.push(white);
collection.push(black);
collection.push(blue);

$(document).ready(function(){
     collection.forEach((o)=>{
        var desc=$("<span/>",{text:o.Description,style:"margin-left:1%;color:blue"});
        var ele=$("<div/>",{text:o.title,style:"margin-left:1%;color:green"});
        ele.append(desc);
        $("#whitet").append(ele);
     });
     $("#searchBox").on('blur',function(){
          $("#whitet").html('');
          var text=$(this).val();
          collection.forEach((o)=>{
           debugger;
           if(o.title.indexOf(text) > -1 || o.Description.indexOf(text) > -1){
            var desc=$("<span/>",{text:o.Description,style:"margin-left:1%;color:blue"});
            var ele=$("<div/>",{text:o.title,style:"margin-left:1%;color:green"});
            ele.append(desc);
            $("#whitet").append(ele);
            }
         });
     })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <p>Products</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div><input type="text" id="searchBox" /></div>
        <div id="whitet">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your JSON data into a string then parse it.

```
var whitet = document.getElementById('whitet');
white_str = JSON.stringify(white);
whiteone = JSON.parse(white_str)
whitet.innerHTML = whiteone.title;
```

You can read about it in

[JSON stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior)

[JSON parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)